# How to turn off nvidia (hybrid graphics)

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, hybrid-graphics

I have a big problem, which prevents me from using Kubuntu 14.04 as my default system. My Asus ul 80 laptop with hybrid graphics (nvidia g210m and intel adapter) seems to use both graphic cards all the time:

```
$ lspci -vnnn | perl -lne 'print if /^\d+\:.+(\[\S+\:\S+\])/' | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:2a42] (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GT218M [GeForce G210M] [10de:0a74] (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

Can I turn off the nvidia card? I do not want to play with the kubuntu anyway and my laptop is constantly very hot, the fan running a lot and the battery live is only halve compared to win7. 
So it would be the easiest solution to just turn nvidia off instead of messing around with switching between the two cards(bumblebee etc. which already has lead to great problems and a reinstall). 
I would really appreciate some help, because until now I am not able to use kubuntu all the time and am afraid it will melt the cpu one day.

Answer (score 20):

Thank you for the hint with the proprietary driver. It saved my kubuntu experience. 
With nvidia version 340 it works perfectly. Furthermore I figured out there was no option in nvidia x server settings menu to switch between the two shown after installing, but you can do it via terminal:

with    `prime-select query` you can see, which one is currently running.

with    `sudo prime-select intel`  you can turn on the intel card.

with    `sudo prime-select nvidia` the other one.

Comment: Worked for Monster Tulpar 18.1 which has an Intel i7 8650H and a GTX1060. Now the PC works cooler and the battery life is obviously extended.

Answer (score 7):

I've been struggling repeatedly on my Asus N55S with an NVidia GT 635M. Especially after the upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04. NVidia is just so evil with the Linux community and its drivers are a well known pain in the neck... Here is what I did:

```
sudo apt-get install bbswitch-dkms
```

then

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

and add the following lines

```
# Blacklist the alternative nvidia module 
blacklist nouveau
# Blacklist the original nvidia module 
blacklist nvidia
```

then

```
$ gksudo gedit /etc/modules
```

and add the following lines

```
# Switch off discrete GPU 
bbswitch load_state=0
```

at last update the initial ramdisk by running

```
$ sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: Worked like a charm with Asus X4GSN and Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Does not work with MSI 1060 TI 6g

Comment: @Nrzonline this answer is for NVidia devices... did you search further?

Comment: Confirmed working with Asus X455LF.

Answer (score 1):

There should be such an option in the **bios**.

Otherwise you can install the **proprietary driver** and under the **nvidia control panel** you can select which chipset you want to use. Select the **Intel** one.