# How to turn off Nvidia GPU in a hybrid graphics laptop using Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, hybrid-graphics, nvidia-prime

I have a HP zbook 15 with hybrid graphics (Intel/nvidia).

I want to save power and only use the Intel GPU in Ubuntu 14.04. I am dual booting between windows 7 (for work) and Ubuntu 14.04. So I can't turn the nvidia GPU of in the bios because I need it in windows 7.

I have tried to use nvidia-prime/nvidia 331 and 340 like this:
[How to turn off nvidia (hybrid graphics)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/551424/how-to-turn-off-nvidia-hybrid-graphics)

But both GPU is turned on at the same time and using a lot of power. Take a look at this:

[image]

Is there any other way for me to turn the nvidia card off?

Comment: It is turned off by nvidia-prime. It won't disappear from lspci.

Comment: But powertop still list it as being used 100%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple, just remove the nvidia drivers from your  Ubuntu install. While using nvidia-prime to switch should work fine,  if you're only going to use the Intel gpu then get rid nvidia  drivers & associated packages, no need for them at all.

Comment: But when I remove the nvidia driver it uses the Nouveau display driver instead, and the Nouveau display driver uses both the Intel and the nvidia gpu?

Comment: Not at all, I have a GeForce GT 755M here, never use nvidia on the linux side. Just check either `System Settings > Details` or `glxinfo | grep Mesa` Also note that here I remove `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` as not needed either

Comment: Thank you for you help, I have removed the nouveau driver and now every program reports it using the Intel GPU.

Comment: I think it would more appropriate to blacklist the driver. See my comment on this post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/551424/how-to-turn-off-nvidia-hybrid-graphics/709552#709552

Answer (score 0):

### acpi_call

If you just want to have long battery life and slow temperature, you can use acpi_call: a linux kernel module that enables calls to ACPI. With acpi_call_GUI you can easily install and configure it via graphic interface.

It is a java program that allows you to:

- install the acpi_call kernel module (kernel would be recompiled automatically after each update);
- Deactivate discrete GPU;
- Automatically deactivate discrete GPU on every boot.

If you have enabled systemd, or if you're using other linux distros that support it, you can use acpi_call_GUI_systemd.

See here: https://github.com/marcoDallas/acpi_call_GUI_systemd

**Installation**

Ensure that you have installed java and git, if not install these packages: git and openjdk-7-jre

After that open a terminal and type the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/marcoDallas/acpi_call_GUI.git
cd acpi_call_GUI
sudo chmod +x install.sh
sudo ./install.sh
```

**How to use**

To launch acpi_call_GUI search it in yuor dash and click on the icon, or type in a terminal:

`sudo java -jar $HOME/acpi_call_GUI.jar`

If you have a separate /home partition, you may need to use this command to launch acpi_call_GUI:

`sudo java -jar /usr/local/bin/acpi_call_GUI/acpi_call_GUI.jar`

[Here's a step-by-step video tutorial that shows how to use this software](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h33bvoR14x8)

---

FROM: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics

Comment: I never seen this acpi_call function, I will give it a try.

Comment: There is no deactivation code for the HP zBook 15.

Comment: You will probably have to contact developers

Comment: Also `systemd` is needed, which is present from version 15.04